# no me centra el menu en css y html

Tags: html, css

Hola por favor necesito de su ayuda en mi curso en linea el instructor escribe esta linea de codigo como se ve en la imagen
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y asi tiene que verse en el navegador
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero a mi no me centra asi sale en mi navegador

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

el problema es que lo tengo escrito igualmente en la parte del wrap como se ve en la imagen

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

por favor les pido su ayuda a resolver este problema. ya van 5 dias que no puedo solucionarlo, no se que esta mal en la parte del wrap del css y html. ya lo intente todo.solo quiero centrar el wrap como se ve en la segunda imagen por favor ayudenme se los agradezco.

```
/* Fuentes */
@font-face {
    font-family: "TrebuchetMS";
    src: url('fonts/TrebuchetMS.ttf');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: "BebasNeue";
    src: url('fonts/BebasNeue.otf');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: "WebSymbolsRegular";
    src: url('fonts/websymbols-regular-webfont.eot');
    src: url('fonts/websymbols-regular-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('fonts/websymbols-regular-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
        url('fonts/websymbols-regular-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
        url('fonts/websymbols-regular-webfont.svg#webSymbolsRegular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

/* GENERALES */

*{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

body{
    background: url("../img/pattern.png");
}


.wrap{
    width: 1200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}


.gear{
    font-family: "WebSymbolsRegular";
}
```

y esto es el html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Master en CSS - Cesar Herrera &Delta; </title>
    <link rel="icon" type="favicon/x-icon" href="img/supertux.png">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css">
</head>

<body>
    <!-- Inicio de cabecera -->
    <header id="header">
        <div class="wrap">
            <div id="logo">
                <span class="gear">S</span>
                <h3>BLOG</h3>
            </div>
            <nav id="menu">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">INICIO</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">BLOG</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">FORMACION</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">CONTACTO</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>

    </header>
    <!-- Fin de cabecera -->
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: pero al margin left de cuantos pixeles le doy?? por favor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

respondiendo a tu duda no se si tienes buen definidas la ruta del estilo de css en la raiz de tu folder, para aprender sobre Vinculación de archivos de hojas de estilo. ([ver aqui](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-link-css-to-html/))

Ruta de los archivos
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Cambie el "css/style.css" por "style.css" en el "index.html"
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Resultado
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]